# Twilio flex - Remove End Chat button

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

How can I remove the 'end chat' button in twilio flex?

I tried with remove component but can't find the component related to end chat button. Where can I find the key for end chat button?

```
Flex.Component.Content.remove(key, {options});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The component containing the end chat button will be "TaskCanvasHeader" and key for it will be "actions"

```
flex.TaskCanvasHeader.Content.remove("actions");
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This is where I took reference from:
https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.33.0/TaskCanvasHeader.html